# Shorten javascript code teaser

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have five input fields. When you delete the content from, let say first, that first input field is populated with input field 2, and the input field 5 is then empty. Again, if you delete the content from the first input field, the content from second goes into the first, and now you have input field four and five empty. And I need that five input field to disappear, to have left only one empty input field. And then again if the third and fourth element are empty, forth should disappear, and so on till there is only first input field left. So, I solve this with hard coded values:

```
if ((document.getElementsByClassName('requestRightsTitle4')[0].value == '')
    && (document.getElementsByClassName('requestRightsEmail4')[0].value == ''))
{
    displayInputField('none', 5);
}

if (
    (document.getElementsByClassName('requestRightsTitle3')[0].value == '')
    && (document.getElementsByClassName('requestRightsEmail3')[0].value == '')
    && (document.getElementsByClassName('requestRightsTitle4')[0].value == '')
    && (document.getElementsByClassName('requestRightsEmail4')[0].value == '')
)
{
    displayInputField('none', 4);
}

if (
    (document.getElementsByClassName('requestRightsTitle2')[0].value == '')
    && (document.getElementsByClassName('requestRightsEmail2')[0].value == '')
    && (document.getElementsByClassName('requestRightsTitle3')[0].value == '')
    && (document.getElementsByClassName('requestRightsEmail3')[0].value == '')
    && (document.getElementsByClassName('requestRightsTitle4')[0].value == '')
    && (document.getElementsByClassName('requestRightsEmail4')[0].value == '')
)
{
    displayInputField('none', 3);
}
```

And now I would like to shorten this code like a real programmer but I don't have the time (sending me to another project) or skills to do so. But I would really like to learn how would that be possible, something like:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (document.getElementsByClassName('requestRightsTitle' + i)[0].value == ''
        && document.getElementsByClassName('requestRightsEmail' + i)[0].value == '')

        displayInputField('none', (i+1));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a listener on all your input fields. If a field is emptied, shift all remaining values to the left and determine which fields need to be displayed (i.e. all fields that have a value and the first empty field).

Here's a complete standalone snippet:

```js
const action = (inputs) => {
  const listener = () => {
    const values = inputs.map(input => input.value).filter(v => v);

    inputs.forEach((input, i) => {
      input.value = values[i] || '';
      input.style.display = values[i] || !i || values[i - 1] ? '' : 'none';
    });
  };


  inputs.forEach((input, i) => input.addEventListener('input', listener));
};


action([...document.querySelectorAll('input')]);
```

```html
<input value="One">
<input value="Two">
<input value="Three">
<input value="Four">
<input value="Five">
```

Answer (score 1):

Better to use `querySelector` when you only want to select the first element. I'd make an object with the value of each element, and then check the object values:

```
const valsAreEmpty = ...vals => vals.every(val => val === '');
const vals = [
  'requestRightsEmail2',
  'requestRightsEmail3',
  'requestRightsEmail4',
  'requestRightsTitle2',
  'requestRightsTitle3',
  'requestRightsTitle4',
].map(classStr => document.querySelector('.' + classStr).value);

if (valsAreEmpty(
  vals.requestRightsTitle4,
  vals.requestRightsEmail4
)) {
  displayInputField('none', 5);
}
if (valsAreEmpty(
  vals.requestRightsTitle3,
  vals.requestRightsEmail3,
  vals.requestRightsTitle4,
  vals.requestRightsEmail4
)) {
  displayInputField('none', 4);
}

// etc
```

If there are even more `Email#` and `Title#` elements, you might use a loop to create the `val`s instead.

Comment: This is a good javascript approach for solving this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Some remarks :

- it looks like you are using html classes to identify single elements in your page

you can use html classes more generically :

```
<input class="requestRightsTitle" />
<input class="requestRightsEmail" />
<input class="requestRightsTitle" />
<input class="requestRightsEmail" />
<input class="requestRightsTitle" />
<input class="requestRightsEmail" />
<input class="requestRightsTitle" />
<input class="requestRightsEmail" />
```

On the javascript side : `document.getElementsByClassName('requestRightsEmail')` will give you a useful array :

```
let emailInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('requestRightsEmail');
emailInputs[0].value = ...
emailInputs[1].value = ...
emailInputs[2].value = ...
...
// note : this array will be 0-indexed.
//   emailInputs[0] will match your 'requestRightsEmail1'
```

This will probably help you on the css side too.

- then you can more easily build and scan arrays of values

e.g :

```
let titles = document.getElementsByClassName('requestRightsTitle')
     .map( e => e.value )
let emails = document.getElementsByClassName('requestRightsEmail')
     .map( e => e.value )

// as said above : '3' matches 'requestRights4'
if (titles[3] == '' && emails[3] == '') {
    displayInputField('none', 5);
}

if (  titles[2] == '' && emails[2] == ''
   && titles[3] == '' && emails[3] == '') {
    displayInputField('none', 4);
}
```

- you can then more easily put this in a loop
- a final note, on what your sample does, and how you can rewrite it :

if `requestRightsEmail3` is *not* empty, you already know that all the tests which include `requestRightsEmail3` will return `false`.

So another way to look at your loop is :
if `i` is *not* empty, stop here, otherwise, show those extra fields :

```
for (let i = 3; i >= 1; i--) {   // <- decreasing loop
  // if one field contains something, stop here :
  if (emails[i] != '' || titles[i] != '') {
    break;
  }

  // otherwise : call your displayInputFields
  displayInputField('none', i);
}
```